# awk array explanation?

Tags: awk

I'm new to awk programming and I'm learning how arrays work. I found this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]' filez filex
```

They put `$1` as index in array and `$2` as value then if `$3` is equal to an index and for this one `$3 = a[$3]`. I can't understand what the meaning is, because the first file has just 2 columns -- where did they come up with `$3` in comparison to `$3` from 2nd file?!?

Input file `filez`:

```
111,111
112,114
113,113
```

Input file `filex`:

```
A,bb,111,xxx,nnn
A,cc,112,yyy,nnn
A,dd,113,zzz,ppp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The aim of this script is to replace the values in the third column of the second file (`filex`) with the corresponding values stored in the second column of the first file (`filez`).

`NR` is the number of the current line relative to the first line of the first processed file. It is a "global" line counter. `FNR` is the number of the current line relative to the beginning of the currently processed file.
`NR==FNR` is a condition that only evaluates to true for the first file. The corresponding action (`{a[$1]=$2;next}`) slurps the whole first file, line by line, into the `a` dictionary, an associative array whose aim is to look up the values of the first file's second column based on the corresponding values in the first column. `next` makes `awk` skip the remaining conditions and restart a cycle, reading the next line.

`$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]` is a condition with a potential side effect (the assignment to `$3`). It is only evaluated for the second file (when `NR==FNR` is false; remember that, when `NR==FNR` was true, `$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]` was skipped). For each line, if the value of the third field is found (as an index) in the `a` dictionary, it is replaced with the corresponding value from the dictionary. Then, if `$3 = a[$3]` evaluates to true, the line is printed (because in AWK programs, which are basically composed of condition (or "pattern")-action pairs, either the condition or the action may be omitted, and an omitted action is equivalent to `print`).

Assuming this shortened `filez`:

```
111,111
112,114
```

and `filex`:

```
A,bb,111,xxx,nnn
A,cc,112,yyy,nnn
```

what happens, step by step, is:

1. the first line of `filez` is read; `NR==FNR` evaluates to `1==1`, true; thus, `{a[$1]=$2;next}` is executed; `a[111]` is set to `111`; `next` means that the rest of the script (`$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]`) is skipped for this line (specifically, `$3` is not used for now); nothing is printed, because the performed action doesn't include any printing command;
2. the second and last line of `filez` is read; `NR==FNR` evaluates to `2==2`, true; `{a[$1]=$2;next}` is executed; `a[112]` is set to `114`; `$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]` is again skipped because of `next`; and again, nothing is printed;
3. the first line of `filex` is read; `NR==FNR` evaluates to `3==1`, false; thus `{a[$1]=$2;next}` is *not* executed; the next condition is evaluated: `$3` is `111` and is an index value of `a`, hence `$3 in a` is true and `$3 = a[$3]` is evaluated; it causes the assignment of `a[111]`, which is `111`, to `$3`; since `111` is not `0` nor the empty string, the condition-assignment also evaluates to true and the current line is printed;

   ```
   A,bb,111,xxx,nnn
   ```
4. the second and last line of `filex` is read; `NR==FNR` evaluates to `4==2`, false; thus `{a[$1]=$2;next}` is *not* executed; the next condition is evaluated: `$3` is `112` and is an index value of `a`, hence `$3 in a` is true and `$3 = a[$3]` is evaluated; it causes the assignment of `a[112]`, which is `114`, to `$3`; since `114` is not `0` nor the empty string, the condition-assignment also evaluates to true and the current line is printed.

   ```
   A,cc,114,yyy,nnn
   ```

Comment: can you please explain what a[$3] refere to , because if we print it it's the same as column 2 of first file so how could that possible and file 1 has no third column !!!!!!

Comment: @DjabriJosef Please, have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: now , it's clear how $3 = a[$3] works but i thought that this is a condition not an action contrary it replace the value of 3rd field and we are not in in an action environment (i.e., not inside {})    !!!

Comment: it can be more clear if it was like this  $3 in a { $3 = a[$3]}

Comment: @DjabriJosef Possibly. But note: 1) `$3 in a {$3=a[$3]}` and `$3 in a && $3=a[$3]` are not equivalent: the first would require also an explicit `print` to print the line. And `$3=a[$3]` is not used as a _condition_ in the former expression (i.e. it doesn't determine whether the line is printed), while it is in the latter. 2) In AWK, the _same_ set of expressions (including assignments) can be used in _both_ patterns (what I called "conditions") and actions. It is not a requirement for patterns not to alter the environment, by design.

Comment: thank you so much for your time you helped me a lot @fra-san

Answer (score 4):

- `BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}` sets input and output field separators to `,`.
- [`NR==FNR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html) is only true for the first file. So, for the first file:

  - `a[$1]=$2` put `$1` as index and `$2` as value in array `a`.
  - [`next`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html) skip the remainder of the script for this line.

Again: `next` means that **the remainder of the script is only executed for the second file** (and third, fourth, ... files if they were present).

- `$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]` If the third field is a key of the array `a`,
  replace the third field with `a[$3]`. Now, since this is not in an action environment (i.e., not inside `{}`), it means that if both conditions
  are true, the current record should be printed. Otherwise, nothing is to be done.

*Generally*, since the condition on the right is an assignment, that will result in true if
the left side is true. However, the assignment is evaluated as false if it assigns
an empty string or the number 0. This may be intended, but it is usually an edge-case
that the programmer failed to notice. To see it, try the awk code with

`filez`:

```
111,111
112,114
113,113
000,000
```

`filex`:

```
A,bb,111,xxx,nnn
A,cc,112,yyy,nnn
A,dd,113,zzz,ppp
A,ee,000,uuu,aaa
```

Notice that, for the last line, although `$3 in a` is true, `$3 = a[$3]`
assigns to 0 and thus the line is not printed!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$3 in a && $3 = a[$3]' filez filex
A,bb,111,xxx,nnn
A,cc,114,yyy,nnn
A,dd,113,zzz,ppp
```

---

On OP request for clarification:

Remember: The array is populated with `a[$1]=$2` **in the first file**, `filez`.
`$3 = a[$3]` is executed **for the second file**, `filex`.
For example: In the second line of `filez`, `a[$1]=$2` -> `a[112] = 114`. In the second line of `filex`, `$3 = a[$3]` -> `112=a[112]=114`.

Comment: can you please explain what a[$3] refere to , because if we print it it's the same as column 2 of first file so how could that possible and file 1 has no third column !!!!!!

Comment: @DjabriJosef As Quasimodo explained, the entire code section involving `$3` is only executed while processing the second file due to the `next` statement in the first rule block `{ ... }` (which is only executed while processing the first file).

Comment: @DjabriJosef I have addressed that in detail in the edit. I hope now it will be clear.

Comment: now , it's clear how $3 = a[$3] works but i thought that this is a condition not an action contrary it replace the value of 3rd field and we r not in in an action environment (i.e., not inside {}) as u said before !!!

Comment: You can do (almost) anything in the condition part: the only criterion is that it should return a boolean value. For complex conditions, I will often call a user-defined awk function in there, and pass it fields as arguments.